# Creating multiple files for different rewrite rules all using the same http conf file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im quite new to rewrite rules so there may be a very simple way of doing this but i cant seem to find much information on it.

Anyway i have a rewriterules file containing about a thousand rules for many different sites, so is there any way to create multiple files just for easier handling of the large amount of rules ?

For example i have three sites:

```
A.com  
B.com  
C.com
```

I want a seperate file for each sites redirects, but also want one universal file for rules that are applicable to all of them ?

Is there anyway to do this ?

Comment: These sites are in same server? symblic link may work.

Comment: Yes they are, how could i use a symbolic link ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the symbolic links, `.htaccess` file including all RewriteRules is located to setting directory [Setting Dir].
Therefore in site A document root, you set the symbolic link as

```
$ cd [Document Root A]
$ ln -s [SettingDir]/.htaccess .htaccess
```

in the same way, in site B, you set

```
$ cd [Document Root B]
$ ln -s [SettingDir]/.htaccess .htaccess
```

...

Comment: I dont use a .htaccess file ?